# Expression expected [user.username?]

Tags: typescript, discord.js

[image]

Why is `user.username?` expecting an expression?, user.username returns a string of the User's username (pretty straight forward), but it won't let me index it into `listOfPlayers[]`

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
if(reaction.emoji.name === '✋' && user.id !== client.user?.id){ // check if it is not a bot
    listOfPlayers[user.username?] = true; // HERE IS THE ERROR
}
```

});

Comment: It's not valid syntax. I don't understand, can you explain what you're trying to indicate with the question mark?

Comment: since the value might be either a string or null I thought I had to add a question mark, if i do not add a question mark it says that the index cant be null @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional chaining only works when connecting *two properties* while accessing or setting. It is not valid syntax to do so at the very end of a property chain.

If the `username` may be null, use an `if` statement to test first:

```
const { username } = user;
if (username !== null) {
  listOfPlayers[username] = true;
}
```

You have to extract the `username` out of the object because type narrowing only works at the *top level* of an object (checking the type of a *child* property does not affect the type of the whole parent - so, extract the child into a standalone variable first).